# ts(2304) в SFC vue 3

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vue3

Внезапно появилась ошибка во всех vue файлах в проекте. Использую Vue 3 + Quasar Framework + TS.

Версия VSCode `1.70.2`

Версия Volar `v0.40.10`

Ошибки типа `Cannot find name 'QIcon'.ts(2304)` или даже на `@click` `Cannot find name 'click'.ts(2304)`. Отключение Volar убирает ошибки, но без него невозможно работать. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

Пробовал https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/discussions/592#discussioncomment-1763880.
Так советует и сам Volar. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему откатом до версии Volar `v0.39.5`.
Любая версия выше вызывает вышеуказанные ошибки. Другого решения не нашел.